# CGD: Drawing on screen in chunks / per row concurrently in drawRect

Tags: grand-central-dispatch

I wanted to just write some thing silly a few days ago during evening and I thought I would watch elements animate on the simulator just to relax. But it turns out it has caused me a lot of headache for the past 2 days.

***Background:***

I thought I would draw a random letter on every pixels on a screen of 320 X 480. 
I would have an array that is filled with 26 letters and make use of `arc4Random % 26` to extract a random letter.

Firstly I made use of `UIGraphicsBeginImageInContextWithOptions` and the add the image to the image view which gets added as my view's subview.

*No problem at all.*

But then I realized, why wait? Let's make a 2 for loops (outer: 480 -> inner: 320)
And once the first inner loop finishes, send that array in `dispatch_async` and have it draw in `drawRect` and then when the next iteration finishes, send that to another `dispatch_async` and so forth until both loop finishes.

My pain began therefrom /-after...............

***Reason:***

The for-loop is too tight and fast. So I ended up wrapping the 2 for loops within a `dispatch_async` and within the inner for loop after I send the array containing 320 elements I put a `sleep(1);`.

But then I realized: It beats the purpose wanting to draw faster by making use of `sleep(1)`. In fact that takes even longer than not using `GCD` at all. Over 25 seconds.

So, I went on trying to use `semaphore` and create one when only 3200 slots are available before sending the array within a `dispatch_async` to `drawRect`;

***Problem:***

Race condition. I would get unexpected array out of bounds errors. The errors are not consistent; some times it happens later, sometimes sooner. I gather this has to do with not using `CGD` correctly.

***So my question is:***

I know by gut feeling that this can be fine-tuned and solved with `GCD`. But I just don't know how. I am at my wit's end.

What I really want is to be able to update the screen's drawing instead of waiting the whole thing gets drawn. Either showing a dot by a dot on the screen or chuck by chuck and not having to call `setNeedsDisplay` but, optimally, to call `setNeedsDisplayinRect` instead.

I thought I would dissect the parts of the drawing elements and send each to its own dispatch_async and each are responsible to drawing only its part and since the run concurrently, it would render the drawing very fast on the screen.

But again, I am out of ideas and ended full of frustration.

```
for(int y = 0; y < 480; y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 320; x++)
    {
        //get a random letter here and insert it into the array (myArray)
    }
    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^
    {
       dispatch_async(dispatch_async_get_main_queue(),^
       {
           [self.myView processRowDrawing:myArray];
       }
    }
    [myArray removeAllObjects];
    //as mentioned: I tried to put a sleep() here because the loop is faster the the drawing
}

- (void)processRowDrawing:(NSMutableArray*)array
{
    for(x = 0; x < array.count; x++)
    {
       //cell here `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` to draw a row
    }
}
```

As for the semaphore version, I simply set a large number in create and signal to call `[self.myView processRowDrawing:myArray];` But since the drawing is slower than the for loop, it didn't help.

Is it possible to solve this in a nice and elegant way with `GCD` by partitioning the drawing part concurrently and send it to `drawRect` and have the parts get shown on the screen bit by bit rather than waiting for it as a whole?

Either row by row or grid by grid and see them get drawn? Again, I would like to use `GCD` here.

Been losing sleep on this. Please advise.

P.S. I have already tried using `CADisplayLink`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This case is unlikely to ever get faster with parallelism. Let's explore why...

Let's break down the "work" that's being done here, in the simple, single threaded case. You're drawing 1 of 26 letters into each pixel in a 320 * 480 grid (i.e. 153,600 times.) This makes no sense, but let's run with it. Unless there's something else that you're not mentioning, CoreText is going to cache all of the setup costs for rendering each of the 26 glyphs the first time any of those letters are rendered. This means that the marginal cost of rendering each letter after the first time it's rendered is constant. When you've rendered the last letter into the last pixel, you hand off a single, completely rendered 320 * 480 bitmap to UIKit to display, and you're done. That cost is irrelevant to this discussion. Let's call the average marginal cost of rendering a single letter into one pixel *A*. The minimum amount of time the single threaded case can take is 153,600 * *A*.

Now let's discuss what's involved in parallelizing this rendering. Let's say to divide it into two tiles of 320 x 240px. In this case, you're hoping the whole task will take 153,600 * *A* / 2 seconds. But there's other costs associated with parallelizing this workflow. Just off the top of my head:

1. The time involved in scheduling/switching to and from those tasks
2. The time involved in setting up the graphics context for each parallel background render
3. The time involved in combining the separate tiles into the single texture that corresponds to the view.

My guess is that the long pole there is going to be #3. In order for parallelizing to show any gain, these extra costs have to be, in total, less than 153,600 * *A* / 2 seconds. Dividing into only two tiles yields the absolute minimum amount of overhead. Any further subdivision just increases the amount of overhead. If dividing it into two tiles isn't faster, certainly no number of tiles greater than two will ever be faster.

You seem to be assuming that the cost of rendering the letters dwarfs the overhead of parallelism. My suspicion is that you're wrong about that.

Comment: Thanks for response. Right, drawing a letter in a single pixel is crazy. My initial intention was to just draw some letters 1 by 1 onto the screen. Bigger ones. But then I wanted to draw a dot, but since I already had made a random letters array, I just went along with it. So, let say all I want is to draw a dot on the screen of 320 x 480. Would it be possible to draw them still row by row / or grid by grid concurrently? Let say I had 16 grids cut out, each would have dimension 60x120 and I set up 16 concurrent queue, each responsible to draw in its dimension and (cont..)

Comment: and..instead of calling `setNeedsDisplay` call `setNeedsDisplayInRect` so that I don't have to refresh the whole screen as if I were to draw them one of one and refresh the screen 320x480 times? Yes, you are right with the calculation, but I thought by having multiple concurrent queues would at least be "faster" to the eye, so that I wouldn't have to wait to for the whole screen to finish drawing before seeing something on the screen. It was really something I wanted to do for fun but ended up being eager to learn whether it would be better achieved by making use of GCD.

Comment: Got frustrated not having been successful as well. The whole idea was to just put something on the screen via `drawRect` and wondered if it would be "faster" or better having a bit of thing shown on the screen without having to wait for the whole thing finishes. The most frustrating part was calling `setNeedsDisplay` in for loops. Often times we create things and add to array by the use of loops but would be nice to be able to call UI update immediately within the loop rather than needing to wait for the loop to finish before calling UI update. That was what I realized while doing this.

Comment: Hence the question. If my case here would not be better achieved by making use of queues. Could you cite me a sample case making use of GCD coordinating UI updates in loops as fast (and correctly) as possible concurrently? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should take a look at this answer I gave to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20404359/438982

Comment: Also, `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` doesn't automagically make rendering cheaper. All it does is provide some more information. In the simplest case, that rect will be passed as the `dirtyRect` to the next invocation of `drawRect:` it's up to your implementation of `drawRect:` to do less work based on that information. In other words, I think might have the relationship between `drawRect:` and `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` backwards.

Comment: OK, I am reading it. Sorry, you mean `setNeedsDisplayInRect` being backward? Also: while glancing thru quickly your answer there at first, I didn't see any mentioning of `semaphore` or `dispatch_source`, so I guess they might not be useful in this case? Maybe I am wrong, just curious. Thanks for link.

Comment: When you call `-[setNeedsDisplayInRect: myRect]`, in the simple case, all that does is cause a later call to `drawRect:` with `dirtyRect` being `myRect`. If you are triggering your background drawing form `drawRect:` in the first place, and then calling `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` from your background drawing, that's not going to work. Also, UIKit is (by and large) main-thread only. For instance, you should *never* call `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` from a background thread. Parallelizing rendering is a complex topic. I get the feeling that you are missing some of the fundamentals here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47887/discussion-between-ipmcc-and-unheilig)